# ¿Por qué mi código se ejecuta incorrectamente? No encuentra el grafo en cualquiera de las 3 opciones

Tags: java, teoría-de-grafos

Esta es la parte del menú donde falla: se ejecuta "bien" pero no hace lo que debería en los métodos de recorrer por anchura (el de profundidad lo hace un amigo de clase), mostrar por lista de adyacencia (matriz lo hace un amigo de clase) o buscar, y al momento de ya crear el grafo y después querer buscarlo, mostrarlo o hacer un recorrido por anchura, aparece un mensaje que yo agregué en caso de no haber creado el grafo: dice que no encontró mi grafo en cualquiera de las 3 opciones, después de ese tengo mi clase grafo, por si ocuparan verla o checarla en dado caso que el error sea ahí.

```
int opcionGRAFO;

do {

  System.out.println("Ingrese un número para lo que desea hacer: ");
  System.out.println("1. Crear grafo");
  System.out.println("2. Recorrer grafo");
  System.out.println("3. Mostrar grafo");
  System.out.println("4. Buscar grafo");
  System.out.println("5. Regresar");
  opcionGRAFO = sc.nextInt();
  int magnitud = 0;
  int[][] grafo = null;

  switch (opcionGRAFO) {
  case 1:
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de grafo (dirigido o no dirigido): ");
    String tipoGrafo = sc.nextLine();
    tipoGrafo = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la magnitud del grafo: ");
    magnitud = sc.nextInt();
    grafo = new int[magnitud][magnitud];
    System.out.println("Ingrese los elementos del grafo: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitud; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < magnitud; j++) {
        grafo[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("El grafo " + tipoGrafo + " con magnitud " + magnitud + " y elementos: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitud; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < magnitud; j++) {
        System.out.print(grafo[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    break;

  case 2:
    int opcionrecor;
    do {
      System.out.println("Recorrido de grafo");
      System.out.println("1. Anchura");
      System.out.println("2. Profundidad");
      System.out.println("3. Regresar");
      System.out.print("Ingrese su opción: ");
      opcionrecor = sc.nextInt();

      switch (opcionrecor) {
      case 1:

        if (grafo == null) {
          System.out.println("No se ha creado ningún grafo todavía.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Recorrido por anchura: ");
          Grafo.recorridoAnchura(grafo, magnitud);
        }
        break;

      case 2:

        break;
      case 3:
        System.out.println("Saliendo del programa.");
        break;

      default:
        System.out.println("Opción no válida. Intente de nuevo.");
        break;

      }
    } while (opcionrecor != 3);
    break;

  case 3:
    int opcionmostr;
    do {
      System.out.println("Mostrado de grafo");
      System.out.println("1. Matriz de adyacencia");
      System.out.println("2. Lista de Adyacencia");
      System.out.println("3. Regresar");
      System.out.print("Ingrese su opción: ");
      opcionmostr = sc.nextInt();

      switch (opcionmostr) {
      case 1:
        if (grafo == null) {
          System.out.println("No se ha creado ningún grafo todavía.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Mostrando grafo: ");
          Grafo.mostraGrafo(grafo);
        }

        break;

      case 2:
        if (grafo == null) {
          System.out.println("No se ha creado ningún grafo todavía.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Mostrando grafo: ");
          Grafo.mostrarGrafo(grafo);
        }

        break;
      case 3:
        System.out.println("Saliendo del programa.");
        break;

      default:
        System.out.println("Opción no válida. Intente de nuevo.");
        break;

      }
    } while (opcionmostr != 3);
    break;
  case 4:
    System.out.println("Busqueda del grafo");
    if (grafo == null) {
      System.out.println("No se ha creado ningún grafo todavía.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Ingrese el nodo inicial: ");
      int nodoInicial = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el nodo final: ");
      int nodoFinal = sc.nextInt();
      if (Grafo.buscarNodo(grafo, nodoInicial, nodoFinal)) {
        System.out.println("El nodo " + nodoFinal + " se encuentra en el grafo.");
      } else {
        System.out.println("El nodo " + nodoFinal + " no se encuentra en el grafo.");
      }
    }

    break;
  case 5:
    System.out.println("Ha salido del programa");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Opción no válida. Intente de nuevo.");
  }
} while (opcionGRAFO != 5);

package com.mycompany.proyecto_3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grafo {

  public static void crearGrafo() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de grafo (dirigido o no dirigido): ");
    String tipoGrafo = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la magnitud del grafo: ");
    int magnitud = input.nextInt();
    int[][] grafo = new int[magnitud][magnitud];
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitud; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < magnitud; j++) {
        grafo[i][j] = -1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Ingrese los elementos del grafo: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitud; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < magnitud; j++) {
        grafo[i][j] = input.nextInt();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("El grafo " + tipoGrafo + " con magnitud " + magnitud + " y elementos: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitud; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < magnitud; j++) {
        System.out.print(grafo[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void recorridoAnchura(int[][] grafo, int magnitud) {
    boolean[] mag = new boolean[magnitud];
    Queue < Integer > cola = new LinkedList < > ();

    mag[0] = true;
    cola.add(0);

    while (!cola.isEmpty()) {
      int nodo = cola.poll();
      System.out.print(nodo + " ");

      for (int i = 0; i < magnitud; i++) {
        if (grafo[nodo][i] == 1 && !mag[i]) {
          mag[i] = true;
          cola.add(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean buscarNodo(int[][] grafo, int nodoInicial, int nodoFinal) {
    boolean[] visitado = new boolean[grafo.length];
    Queue < Integer > cola = new LinkedList < > ();
    visitado[nodoInicial] = true;
    cola.add(nodoInicial);
    while (!cola.isEmpty()) {
      int nodo = cola.poll();
      if (nodo == nodoFinal) {
        return true;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < grafo.length; i++) {
        if (grafo[nodo][i] == 1 && !visitado[i]) {
          visitado[i] = true;
          cola.add(i);
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void mostrarGrafo(int[][] grafo) {
    if (grafo == null) {
      System.out.println("No se ha creado ningún grafo todavía.");
      return;
    }

    ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> listaAdyacencia = new ArrayList < > ();
    for (int i = 0; i < grafo.length; i++) {
      ArrayList < Integer > adyacentes = new ArrayList < > ();
      for (int j = 0; j < grafo.length; j++) {
        if (grafo[i][j] == 1) {
          adyacentes.add(j);
        }
      }
      listaAdyacencia.add(adyacentes);
    }
    System.out.println(listaAdyacencia);
  }

  public static void mostraGrafo(int[][] grafo) {
    if (grafo == null) {
      System.out.println("No se ha creado ningún grafo todavía.");
      return;
    }

    for (int[] fila: grafo) {
      System.out.println(fila);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que inicializas de nuevo el grafo en cada iteración del bucle do-while.

```
  do {

        System.out.println("Ingrese un número para lo que desea hacer: ");
        System.out.println("1. Crear grafo");
        System.out.println("2. Recorrer grafo");
        System.out.println("3. Mostrar grafo");
        System.out.println("4. Buscar grafo");
        System.out.println("5. Regresar");
        opcionGRAFO = sc.nextInt();
        int magnitud = 0;
        int[][] grafo = null;
```

Es decir, cada vez que seleccionas una opción del menú principal, el grafo comienza siempre siendo null, no se guarda. Lo único que tienes que hacer es sacar esa inicialización fuera de ese bucle para conseguir que se guarde el grafo.

```
    int[][] grafo = null;

    do {

        System.out.println("Ingrese un número para lo que desea hacer: ");
        System.out.println("1. Crear grafo");
        System.out.println("2. Recorrer grafo");
        System.out.println("3. Mostrar grafo");
        System.out.println("4. Buscar grafo");
        System.out.println("5. Regresar");
        opcionGRAFO = sc.nextInt();
        int magnitud = 0;
```

Por otro lado, el método mostrarGrafo no te va a dar un resultado legible porque estás intentando escribir directamente un array de enteros.

```
    for (int[] fila : grafo) {
        System.out.println(fila);
    }
```

Aquí puedes ver a qué me refiero

[image: Mostrado de grafo]

No recuerdo bien qué es exactamente la matriz de adyacencia pero quizás lo que quieres hacer sea esto

```
    for (int[] fila : grafo) {
        for (int j : fila) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Introduciendo los mismos datos y las mismas opciones, así obtenemos

[image: Mostrado de grafo corregido]